# python-requests: "NoneType" has no attribute read

Tags: python, api, python-requests, python-3.6

I'm trying to create a Python Wrapper for an upcoming API, so far I've been getting along well, but I keep bumping my head into the same problem. When making a POST request to add a mod to a game through the API, I feed the following dict  item into the POST request

```
{'name': "Necro's Test Mod", 'name_id': None, 'summary': "This is a test mod submitted through the API using python's request library.", 'description': "I'm only about 43% sure this will actually work, whats more likely is that it will fail and return some messed up error with some even weirder error message before i am contacted by the mod.io developper saying they have personally revoked my api key (This isn't actually true i just need words", 'homepage': 'www.edain.wikia.com', 'metadata_blob': 'None', 'stock': 1, 'tags': ['cool', 'python', 'api'], 'logo': <_io.BufferedReader name='C:\\Users\\Clement\\Pictures\\Background\\7z6cSaI-lord-of-the-rings-wallpaper-hd.jpg'>}
```

And that dictionnary is added as follows

```
BASE_PATH = "https://api.test.mod.io/v1"
headers = {
  'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + client.access_token,
  'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
  'Accept': 'application/json'
}

r = requests.post(BASE_PATH + '/games/181/mods'.format(self.id), files = dict, headers = headers)
```

However it returns the following traceback, leading me to believe that the API returns a blank response

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Clement\Desktop\mod.io\test.py", line 40, in <module>
    new_mod = game.add_mod(newmod)
  File "C:\Users\Clement\Desktop\mod.io\modio\game.py", line 83, in add_mod
    r = requests.post(BASE_PATH + '/games/{}/mods'.format(self.id), files = mod.__dict__, headers = headers)
  File "C:\Users\Clement\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 112, in post
    return request('post', url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Clement\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 58, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Clement\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 494, in request
    prep = self.prepare_request(req)
  File "C:\Users\Clement\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 437, in prepare_request
    hooks=merge_hooks(request.hooks, self.hooks),
  File "C:\Users\Clement\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 308, in prepare
    self.prepare_body(data, files, json)
  File "C:\Users\Clement\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 496, in prepare_body
    (body, content_type) = self._encode_files(files, data)
  File "C:\Users\Clement\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 159, in _encode_files
    fdata = fp.read()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'read'
```

Here's the [documentation](https://docs.mod.io/#add-mod) for the particular POST request I am attempting.

Comment: Should you have instead used `data=dict`? Also, don't use "dict" to name variables.

Comment: What is the value of the `dict` variable?

Comment: Value of the dict variable is at the top of the answer.
@cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ When I use data=dict, it tells me that I need to supply attributes such as logo, name and summary, which I have already done

Answer (score 1):

The `files` argument is meant for file uploads. You probably want to use `data` instead here.

```
r = requests.post(
    BASE_PATH + '/games/181/mods'.format(self.id), 
    data = dict, 
    headers = headers
)
```

You get this error because requests expects the value of `name_id` to be a file pointer with a `read()` method. But in your payload it's `None`.

And don't use `dict` as a variable name.

Comment: I am indeed trying to upload a file, and at the same time sending some data along with it. `dict` is just a temporary variable for use on stack overflow I thought it was more explicit than the actual variable name `newmod.__dict__`